Loading data from file to database, file has field which is primary key, how to implement hibernate bulk inserts. can't have auto generated Id
Entity looks like this.
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTION")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Transaction {
@Id
@Column(name = "ACCOUNT")
private String account;
@Column(name = "AMOUNT")
private BigDecimal amount;
@Column(name = "TIMESTAMP")
private Timestamp timestamp;
}

Data file looks like this, where "account" is primary key.
account           amount timestamp
5113971498870901,-546.68,2018-02-08 17:46:12
I'm not seeing bulk inserts, instead I see select and inserting one record at a time.
@Bean
@StepScope
public RepositoryItemWriter<Transaction> writer() {
RepositoryItemWriter<Transaction> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
writer.setRepository(transactionRepository);
return writer;
}


What's your chunk size? Spring batch reads and writes data based on chunk size. If your chunk size is one, it will read and write records one by one.

chunk size is 100
